# How to custom sort a list of cards in Python?

Tags: list, python-3.x, sorting

I haven't been able to find a solution to this problem anywhere (I've checked many of the custom sort questions) and I've only just started learning Python, apologies if this is a repeat or too specific.

I'm coding a card game that has the user playing against the program. The list that needs to be sorted is the hand of cards, each card represented as two characters (eg. `7c` for the seven of clubs, or `Td` for the ten of diamonds). I want to arrange the cards so that the ranks are in the following order: `3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, J, Q, K, A, 2` and `T`.

So if I had a hand that was `['3d', 'Ac', '6h', 'Kd', '2s']`, it would be presented as `['3d', '6h', 'Kd', 'Ac', '2s']`.

Answer (score 1):

First, define the order. Then sort your hand by that order:

```
In [39]: order = "3456789JQKA2T"

In [40]: hand = ['3d', 'Ac', '6h', 'Kd', '2s']

In [41]: hand.sort(key=lambda c:order.index(c[0]))

In [42]: hand
Out[42]: ['3d', '6h', 'Kd', 'Ac', '2s']
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much. I'd tried a similar solution but with sorted() instead of list.sort().